# The HAL Browser doesn't get autoconfigured correctly in spring-data-rest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest, hal

I have install HAL Browser in my spring boot app.

In the documentation they say it will be started at `http://localhost:8080`.

but it got started at http://localhost:8080/api which is my repositories.

So it override the base path of my spring-data-rest api.

Then inside the HAL browser app, I can see all of my repositories.

If I try a GET, it try's to query them under `http://localhost:8080/api/api/entities` , which return 404.

The original endpoint `http://localhost:8080/api/entities` also return 404.

Is the plugin broken with latest spring, spring-data, spring-hateoas modules ?

If I change the data rest api path to "/" it work fine.

Also, I would like to know if it's possible to authorize the client using OAuth. I use spring-security-oauth and all the request are rejected .

**Edit** It appear the plugin doesn't support different path than `/`
Also, it is not possible to support `spring-data-oauth`, my best chance is to install HAL Browser my self

Comment: It will get started on the URL you provided for your rest endpoints, which by default is root. Used it in a workshop last week without any problems, so I would say the flaw is in your configuration / setup.

Comment: Well, my rest endpoint is at /api, so this is why the HAL browser start under that path. However, this break my api and doesn't tell me why HAproxy use wrong link at the beginning

Comment: What has HAProxy to do with this?!

Comment: Sorry I wanted to write HAL browser !

Comment: Add some code/configuration to your question if you want an answer.

Comment: I've updated the question. I volontary didn't had any configuration has I don't think this will be relevant here.

Comment: Spring data oauth? Your questions gets more and more confusing. You are also no asking 2 question in 1 question. So again no the plugin isn't broken as I used it 2 weeks ago (spring boot 1.3.8 and 1.4.2) so ti must be something in your configuration (which you haven't added). So the answer to your current question is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use complete URL like `http://localhost:8080/api/entities`
You should use only the URI like -
`/api/api/entities`